# Stick HTML element to bottom of container, without ever clipping its top

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I have a container `div` element, and an inner element (in this case a picture) within this container. I would like the following to happen:

- If the container div is taller than the inner element, the inner element should be placed at the bottom of the container.
- If the container div is smaller than the inner element should instead be placed at the top of the container and the bottom is clipped.

The main difficult I am having is that the inner element's height is variable. Ideally, I would like to have a CSS-only solution (it is significantly easier if using JavaScript of course).

#### Partial Solution

In cases where the inner element height is known and fixed, I have managed to get the desired outcome with the following ([CodePen link](https://codepen.io/JP-Ellis/pen/ExdjpMb)):

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: clip;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  container-type: size;
}

.inner {
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, yellow);
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
}

.option1 {
  position: absolute;
  @container (max-height: 400px) {
    top: 0;
  }
  @container (min-height: 400px) {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if this can provide a useful starting point for any solutions. This could be quite easily fixed by being access the current element's height in the `@container` queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use a pseudo element and set `flex-direction: column` for `.container`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: clip;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
}
```

The pseudo-element `::before` has a height of 0 (since we didn't specify any) so it is invisible to users. If it had some height, however, our layout (without `display: flex`) would look like this:

```
┌────────────────────────┐
│        ::before        │
├──────┬─────────────────┤
│      │                 │
│.inner│                 │
│      │                 │
├──────┘                 │
│                        │
└────────────────────────┘
```

The combo of `display: flex` (make it a flexbox), [`flex-direction: column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) (place elements vertically) and [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) (maximum space between elements) makes the two elements touch two opposite sides:

```
┌────────────────────────┐
│        ::before        │
├────────────────────────┤
│                        │
├──────┐                 │
│      │                 │
│.inner│                 │
│      │                 │
└──────┴─────────────────┘
```

If `.container` is not as high as the sum of its children's heights, it will first try to shrink its children. Since `::before` never had any height to begin with, and `.inner` has already fit its content, the space between them collapse to 0 and `.inner` will be `clip`-ped:

```
┌────────────────────────┐
│        ::before        │
├──────┬─────────────────┤
│      │                 │
│.inner│                 │
└──────┴─────────────────┘
```

Try it:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  container.style.height = this.value + 'px';
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 30px 0;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: clip;
  height: 200px;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
}

.inner {
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, yellow);
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="100" max="1000" step="1" value="200">

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner option1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam interdum purus nec interdum tristique. Maecenas eleifend, libero nec varius cursus, lacus eros elementum odio, eget convallis risus erat ut velit. Pellentesque ut ex lobortis, hendrerit ipsum
    ut, pretium dui. Morbi porta viverra eros eget malesuada. Praesent sed metus eu dui fermentum sagittis. Aliquam blandit ultricies hendrerit. Integer dignissim enim est, id vestibulum ante ultricies eu. Cras at est quis sem luctus finibus. Mauris in
    maximus turpis.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Such a simple solution. If you wouldn't mind, could you elaborate on why it works (I can now see why, but for someone not as familiar with `flex` the explanation might help a lot)

Comment: Added an explanation and a bit of non-ASCII art.

Comment: @JP-Ellis this is a bit over-complicated. You don't need flex-direction: column, justify-content and the pseudo element ... simply add margin-top: auto to your inner element